# ssh connection still alive even after physical disconnect and reconnect

Tags: linux, ssh

I have `ssh`'d into multiple remote machines. I don't have any sort of special connection resuming software that I'm aware of (unless... is SSH capable of doing it?)

I then need to move my laptop to a new location, so I unplug all the hardwiring, including ethernet. I move to the new location. I plug everything back in, including ethernet.

None of the ssh connections were interrupted. Indeed, I can still interact with them. Pretty much *all* other software I'm aware of will immediately notice the physical disconnect and follow up with reporting connection errors and etc. I want to learn how and why `ssh` differs from most normal software.

I've tried

- googling `ssh connection alive after disconnect`
- googling `ssh physical disconnect`. That got me [someone else noticing what I believe to be the same (or similar) effect](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2014-October/080680.html), but the mail chain ends there (at the guy's observation)
- googling `ssh alive`, which sends me to various documentation about `ServerAliveInterval` for `ssh-config`. I don't believe that's strictly relevant since that's there specifically to keep the connection alive when it's *idle*? Or do I misunderstand that?

Frankly I'm not sure what phrase or keyword for which I need to search. Can someone please explain this magic or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have noticed this same behaviour with just simple TCP sockets -- disconnect cable, then reconnect, and I can still communicate -- so SSH is not special that way.  I think what you are seeing is normal.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` should survive only short term disconnects (TCP timeout), but might even a bit longer (configured as `ServerAlive*` client option and `ClientAlive*` server option). And only if you "return to the same IP" (VPN, static network configuration).

It would be useful to know what version are you using as a client and what is the SSH server. The Roaming feature was removed in recent versions of openssh, but you would notice if you would be using this feature, because it asked for reconnection.